# Why is configure autoscaling greyed out on sagemaker

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to configure autoscaling for my endpoint on sagemaker. However I cannot do it in the UI as the button is greyed out after I click on a model variant. I do however have another model setup before where the button is not greyed out.

Why is this not available for some models on sagemaker but it is for others?

Answer (score 0):

Any type of model hosted on SageMaker endpoint does support autoscaling. Its not restricted by model types either. How ever i can think of the following reasons due to which it might be disabled for one of the endpoints.

1. Are you seeing these two models in the same AWS account and using the same IAM role to update the autoscaling policies? If not, that is the issue. Update your IAM policies and the button shall work.
2. SageMaker doesn't support autoscaling for [burstable instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances.html) such as T2, because they already allow for increased capacity under increased workloads. Is your endpoint in question running on these burstable type instances? If yes, you know the reason now. Just change the instance to any other type and it should work fine.